# 3 modal gaussian distribution in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, statistics

I am working with statistical data. I have made 3 normal distributions but i want to make gaussian mixture distibution of my data set. I want to represent density estimation of my data by 3 Modal Gaussian Distribution.

I am using this command but i donot know the feature that can be used to make 3 modal gaussian distribution curve.

```
pd = fitdist(offset_rem_limit_sif_diff','Kernel','Kernel','epanechnikov')
y = pdf(pd,x);
plot(x,y, 'b')
```

Is there any distribution which can be used to draw 3 modal Gaussian distribution curve.

The 3 distributions are shown in figure as green, red and yellow.

If someone help me out it will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [gmdistribution](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/gmdistribution.html) should fit your needs. It allows you to define a gaussian mixture distribution object with as many gaussian distributions as you want.

Here is a working example with 3 components:

```
x = (-2:0.01:2).';
mu = [-0.5 -0.1 1].';
sigma = [0.1 0.4 0.2].';

for i = 1:3
    pd = makedist('Normal',mu(i),sigma(i));
    y = pdf(pd,x);

    hold on;
    plot(x,y);
    hold off;
end

s(1,1,:) = sigma;
p = ones(1,3).' / 3;

gm = gmdistribution(mu,s,p);
y = pdf(gm,x);

hold on;
plot(x,y,'--');
hold off;
```

Output (the image is being shrunk and results in poor quality graphics, click on it to enlarge it to full size):

[image: Output]

Comment: Tommaso Belluzzo thanks a lot. Great explanation and worked like a piece of cake for me. Thumbed up and selected.